# GRUB not showing on cold boot but on warm boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I have a dual boot between Windows 8 + Ubuntu 14.04 (UEFI), but what is happening now is I am booted directly to windows when I first start my computer or restart from Ubuntu.
I can see my grub only when I restart from Windows.

These are the values of my `/etc/default/grub` :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/
Do you want to boot to Ubuntu by default?  Do you want to see the menu?  Do you want to boot to the OS you last booted???  ;-)

Comment: I guess you want grub menu always, if it is so, then check the answer i added

Comment: @Fabby I used to see the Grub menu, but now I see them sometimes only.

Comment: What brand/model computer. And did you upgrade to 8.1. Many vendors & 8.1 seem to only want you to boot Windows. And from Windows it may "let" you boot one time using UEFI one time reboot entry into another system. Work around typically is to rename the hard drive boot entry bootx64.efi and make it grub. Then booting hard drive gives grub menu. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: Sony VIOA Fit 14 SVF-14A15SNB
No, I just installed windows 8, followed by ubuntu. My updates are also off on windows.

Comment: Do (did) you happen to have an Asus motherboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I even tried reinstalling the grub, but that too could not help.
The problem got solved when I

- Enable secure Boot
- Restart
- Disable Secure Boot

  Now everything seems to work again. I don't know why that happened. If anyone know the reason please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Edit grub file by executing following command in Terminal :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and then uncomment `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` by removing `#` before them and save the file.

Then execute following command in terminal :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and grub will always load.

Comment: I tried what you said, and it did not worked.
those were the values when I actually started facing the problem, so I just tried commenting them out, after seeing somewhere.

Comment: Do you have some kinda setting in your BIOS like "Which OS to boot", If there is such setting , change it to other.

Comment: No,my laptop does not have any such settings. I have used those on other laptops, but my laptop doesn't support it.